# Custom annotation processor not locating annotated classes

Tags: java, annotations

What would prevent a custom AnnotationProcessor from locating an annotated classes?

The processor and custom annotation is defined in a different module from where the annotated class resides:

```
| --
   -- app
   -- annotations
      -- src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

The app module references the annotation project in its gradle.properties as follows:

```
annotationProcessor project(":annotations")
```

The gradle.properties of the app module also has this plugin defined:

```
id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version "0.21"
```

The custom annotation processing code starts with the usual lines:

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {

        Set<?> elements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(UnitOfWork.class);
```

Where UnitOfWork is my custom annotation.

**UPDATE 1:** 
I have my custom annotation processor registered in annotation/src/main/resources/META-INF/javax.annotation.processing.Processor.

Comment: Did you register your custom annotation processor in `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`?

Comment: Did you declare the `@SupportedAnnotationTypes` and `@SupportedSourceVersion`annotations on the custom annotation processor (and extend `AbstractProcessor`)?

Comment: yes I did on the annotations module and yes, I implemented getSupportedAnnotationTypes() as follows:  @Override
 public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
  return ImmutableSet.of(UnitOfWork.class.getCanonicalName());
 }